# Exception When Accessing Server Variables

Tags: .net, wcf

I've created a RESTful WCF 4.0 service.  To capture and log unhandled exceptions, I've created an Error Handler in which I'd like to gather server variables for logging purposes.  However, accessing HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables throws a "Value does not fall within the expected range" exception:

```
public class MyErrorHandler : IErrorHandler, IServiceBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        IErrorHandler errorHandler = new VirusInfoErrorHandler();

        foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase channelDispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = channelDispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;

            if (channelDispatcher != null)
            {
                channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(errorHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        // I'd like to log here but accessing
        // HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables
        // throws a "Value does not fall within the expected range" exception.

        return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
    }
}
```

My config is as follows:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Rest">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" httpHelpPageEnabled="False" />
        <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="ACME.MyAuthorizationManager, ACME.Authorization" />
        <errorHandler /> 
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name ="errorHandler" type="ACME.MyErrorHandlerElement, ACME.MyErrorHandler"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint name="" faultExceptionEnabled="true" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"  />
    </webHttpEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAppAccess" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The service class and method is:

```
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="/my-method", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Message MyMethod()
    {
        // might return good things
        // might throw an exception in downstream tiers
    }
}
```

Is there not a way to retrieve the server variables from the context from WCF?

Comment: Why do you want to retrieve these "variables"? They don't really exist in any case. Instead, look to see what you _can_ get from the various context objects.

Comment: When you say "they don't really exist in any case", can you explain?  I'd care about retrieving things like the requestor's IP address and the server's name.  Is that possible from the WebOperationContext?  I'm not seeing a way from an IErrorHander.

Comment: "server variables" are a fiction invented by web servers to make it easier for scripting languages to access this information. There aren't really a set of variables somewhere. Brief research suggests that you can access `OperationContext` from within `ProvideFault`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your service class marked with the following attribute?

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```